# Possible to get classpath of Type object? (e.g com.test.xyz.CLASSNAME)

Tags: java, path, classpath

I've been searching around, but I have not found what I am looking for. Essentially, what I am trying to do is get the class path of a Java object in the form

> com.path.xyz.CLASSNAME

. Is this possible to do.

I currently have a object as follows:

```
 List<Objects> x;
 for(Object t: x){
    getPath(t)
 }
```

Comment: `List<Object>`, not `List<Objects>`. `Objects` is a utility class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `t.getClass().getCanonicalName()` to get the full class name...